# GLM combining results

Tags: r, glm

I'm writing a Sweave file for clearer presentation of `glm()` results. The `glm` is for calculating premium prices of insurances. Usually 2 separate `glm`s are used for this. One for claim frequency and one for claim severity. To get the final price I would have to multiply coefficient estimates of the 2 models, according to categorization. If both models have the same independent variables with the same levels the problem is trivial. I can just multiply the fitted values of both and it's done. The problem arises when the factors have different levels, a cause of merging them to get better results. Lets say I have factor age for frequency with 3 levels 0-25,25-50,50-110 and for severity with 2 levels 0-25,25-110. I want to combine the fitted values to be multiplied in the following sense:

```
Frequency      Severity
0-25              0-25
25-50            25-110
50-110          25-110
```

In other words, the fitted values should be multiplied only when the categories are in the same range. This should also work for non numeric categorizations. For instance

```
Frequency       Severity
a                     ab
b                     ab
c                     c
```

Is there any function/package in R that would allow me to do that? If not, what other ways exist? 
Currently my only idea is to use custom labels for factor levels and then using string comparisons between them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create code for transforming your dataset in model-specific ways, and then call it before computing the predictions. This generalises easily to situations where your models involve different subsets of variables, or are of different forms completely. Since this is R and not SAS, you can do it all in one function.

```
predict_combined <- function(glm.cf, glm.cs, newdata)
{
    newdata.cf <- within(newdata, {
        age <- cut(age, c(0, 25, 50, 110))
        ...
        ...
    })

    newdata.cs <- within(newdata, {
        age <- cut(age, c(0, 25, 110))
        ...
        ...
    })

    pred.cf <- predict(glm.cf, newdata.cf, type="resp")
    pred.cs <- predict(glm.cs, newdata.cs, type="resp")
    pred.cf * pred.cs
}
```

This can be turned into a one-liner, but that would probably obfuscate more than it would elucidate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand it correctly. With the code that you've written, I still get the same number of predictions as there are rows in my data, when I only want to get as many predictions as there are relevant fitting combinations of age from both models. For example in the age example, I'd only want 3 predictions. The thing that interests me is the 3 different premiums I'll get from combining those 2 models. So as an output I'd like a data frame with 3 columns. First two the levels of factors of each model and in the last column the appropriate premium.

Comment: Are you calculating scores for frequency and severity differently?